# gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background not working

Tags: command-line, bash, desktop-background, gsettings

I am trying to download a daily picture and set it as my background image with:

```
#!/bin/bash
# clear cache
PICS="/home/pvlkmrv/Pictures"

rm -f ${PICS}/wall.jpg
rm -f ${PICS}/photo-of-the-day

# download photo-of-the-day page
wget http://photography.nationalgeographic.com/photography/photo-of-the-day -O ${PICS}/photo-of-the-day

# parse the url out from the file
url=`cat ${PICS}/photo-of-the-day | grep 'images.nationalgeographic.com.*cache.*990x742.jpg' | cut -d '"' -f 2`

# download the photo
wget http:$url -O ${PICS}/wall.jpg

# set the desktop background
URI=file:///${PICS}/wall.jpg
echo ${URI}
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options 'centered'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri ${URI}
```

The image downloads just as expected, but the background is not actually set. Strangely, it works if I modify URI to include more or fewer forward-slashes, but it does so only once. I end up having to modify the script in what should be a meaningless way every time in order to make this section work.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Since you're always using the same filename, you don't need to run the `gsettings` command again each run. It should detect a changed file and automatically update the displayed background. I suggest commenting out everything after `wget http:$url -O ${PICS}/wall.jpg`.

Comment: This does not work; I have to tell the system to reload the image. You are likely correct, but it would take a shutdown or log out to make the program reload the image from the disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the issue: Even if I go to the file, right click, and say "Set as Wallpaper...", nothing happens. So I postulated that it's the fact the filename isn't changing each time; Linux has some kind of cost-saving I'm-not-actually-going-to-refresh-because-that's-the-same-image feature. To force the system to recognize it's a new picture each time, vary the filename like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# clear cache
PICS="/home/pvlkmrv/Pictures"
RAND=$RANDOM

rm -f ${PICS}/*.jpg
rm -f ${PICS}/photo-of-the-day

# download photo-of-the-day page
wget http://photography.nationalgeographic.com/photography/photo-of-the-day -O ${PICS}/photo-of-the-day

# parse the url out from the file
url=`cat ${PICS}/photo-of-the-day | grep 'images.nationalgeographic.com.*cache.*990x742.jpg' | cut -d '"' -f 2`

# download the photo
wget http:$url -O ${PICS}/wall${RAND}.jpg

# set the desktop background
URI="file://${PICS}/wall${RAND}.jpg"
echo ${URI}
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options 'centered'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "${URI}"
```

Answer (score 2):

try it this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
# clear cache
PICS="/home/pvlkmrv/Pictures"

rm -f "${PICS}/wall.jpg"
rm -f "${PICS}/photo-of-the-day"

# download photo-of-the-day page
wget "http://photography.nationalgeographic.com/photography/photo-of-the-day" -O "${PICS}/photo-of-the-day"

# parse the url out from the file
url="`cat ${PICS}/photo-of-the-day | grep 'images.nationalgeographic.com.*cache.*990x742.jpg' | cut -d '\"' -f 2`"

# download the photo
wget "http:$url" -O "${PICS}/wall.jpg"

# set the desktop background
# only two slashes here, because the PICS var already has a leading slash
URI="file://${PICS}/wall.jpg"
echo ${URI}
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options 'centered'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "${URI}"
```

Comment: Yes, just adding quotes around the URI and ${URI} seems to fix it.

Comment: No! Now it's not working again, and the only change I've made is the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can either quote the full `URI` variable as cmks have shown, or ensure that `file://` and `wall.jpg` are quoted, like so:

```
URI="file:///"${PICS}"/wall.jpg"
```

Here's a small improvement of your script. Variables are used to shorten the command line. File is saved to `/tmp`, which is deleted each time system is restarted, so you don't have to manually clear cache. AWK is used to improve parsing and decrease piping. `wget` directly writes to AWK to avoid saving extra files

```
#!/bin/bash

# set variables to shorten lines
FILE="/tmp/photo_of_the_day"
PAGE="http://photography.nationalgeographic.com/photography/photo-of-the-day"
SEARCH="images.nationalgeographic.com.*cache.*990x742.jpg"

# get image URI directly
IMAGE=$(wget "$PAGE" -O - -o /dev/null  | awk -F'"' -v regex="$SEARCH" '$0~ regex {print $2}')

# download the photo
wget http:$IMAGE -O "$FILE"

# set the desktop background
URI="file:///$FILE"
echo ${URI}
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options 'centered'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "${URI}"
```